# regular expression failing and I can't see why

Tags: php, regex

I think I've been looking at this too long.
I can't seem to get this regex to work.

Code:

```
$pattern='/([0-9A-Z\-])*(#)(\s*)/i'; 

if (preg_match($pattern,'B-25-1abc-SW-19# ',$matches) )  {
    echo $matches[0];
}
```

(from the comments):
I was expecting it to print out the `B-25-1abc-SW-19#` text, but its not printing anything because its not getting into the true part of the if statement.

I also tried changing the pattern to look like:

```
$pattern='/^$([0-9A-Z\-])*(#)(\s*)/i';
```

But that hasn't fixed it either.

Comment: What do you expect it to do and what does it do?

Comment: I was expecting it to print out the B-25-1abc-SW-19# text... but its not printing anything out... no matches...

Comment: If it is matching other stuff it _shouldn't match_, it is because you need to anchor it with `^$`

Comment: @dot in my test, it does print it.

Comment: This exact code prints out `B-25-1abc-SW-19# ` for me

Comment: Just tried on http://www.regextester.com, it matches. It would be better if you could give us your debugged output(e.g. print_r $matches)

Comment: it never gets into the true part of the if statement.

Comment: try the following
if(preg_match($pattern,'B-25-1abc-SW-19# ',$matches) > 0) { var_dump($matches) }

Answer (score 1):

You have probably misplaced your quantifier (although it should still match the whole string):

```
$pattern='/([0-9A-Z\-])*(#)(\s*)/i';
```

should be:

```
$pattern='/([0-9A-Z\-]*)(#)(\s*)/i';
```

If it really is just `matches[0]` you are after, you should check your original string, perhaps you have some utf8 character for your `-` that is not the minus-character you have in your pattern (or the other way around).

Comment: Wouldn't actually make a difference unless the `$1` capture group was accessed.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski True, but I am guessing that is what the OP is after. The regex should match where `matches[0]` is concerned so this is the one possible problem I can see.

Comment: How can I test for utf8 character scenario?

Comment: @dot You could see if there is a difference between your string and `htmlentities($your_string)`. There are probably other ways, but this is the first that comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

I just as well tried it on phpfiddle, it does return me the results. I have also made a few editings to your regex.

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3x6-6w2

Perhaps you have an issue with the string you're working on?

Answer (score 0):

The star was after the first ) instead of ] :)

```
            $pattern='/([0-9A-Z\-]*)(#)(\s*)/i'; 

            $matches= array();
            if (preg_match($pattern,'B-25-1abc-SW-19# ',$matches) )  {
               print_r($matches);
            }   

//N.B.
//http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
//If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.
```